# Error after installing android studio in windows(downloading components)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried installing different versions of Android Studio several times but I get this error every time while downloading components after installation. This is the error,

> "The following SDK components were not installed: Android SDK Tools,
>   Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 and Google Repository".

It gives option to retry but it again gives the same error.
I have jdk1.8.0_51 installed on my laptop.

Comment: delete existing sdk and restart your android studio , it will show you option for installing sdk .

Comment: I have deleted sdk from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android and restarted android studio but again there is same error, "Android Support Repository, Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 and 3 more SDK components were not installed"

Comment: you are creating new project or open existing project?

Comment: I have just started working on it, creating a new project

Comment: As I am new here I am not allowed to post screeenshots. The error comes after installation while downloading components. The error is, "The following SDK components were not installed: Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 and Google Repository".

Comment: open sdk manager and install Android SDK Tools.

Comment: look here i put screen short of my sdk tool setting https://ibb.co/gB74Hc

Comment: There is some problem with-                                                             
-Google Repository version 58
- Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 
- Android SDK Tools version 26.1.1
- Android Support Repository version 47.0.0                                                I am not able to install above mentioned tools.                                           Can you please give me your mail address so that I can send you a screenshot of the error?